# Custom Ajax in Drupal

Tags: php, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

I'm looking to create a custom Ajax call in Drupal 7.

It seems that the way this was recommended is to add a hook menu in any of the custom modules (https://www.drupal.org/node/305747).  However in my case, the ajax call needs to be on the home page which should call a function in a custom module that is not being loaded.

Is there a way to write a custom hook menu to achieve the functionality?

Comment: You can use the form api and the drupal ajax framework to do it and then no need to implement your own hook_menu. What eactly are you trying to do?

Comment: That link you posted to is very old and doing it the standard ajax way without any of drupal 7s form api or ajax functionality.

Comment: I'm basically trying to make an ajax call on page load of the home page to load some content async.  The function i'm trying to call is located under a custom module i created, but i can move that functionality if needed.